# Issues authenticating with php's ssh2

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ssh, osx-mountain-lion

I am attempting to open an SSH connection between my two servers at script runtime using PHP's SSH2, and got somewhere using information from http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/24/make-ssh-connections-with-php/. That said, using the following code, I keep failing to authenticate. It seems that the two servers are communicating, but simply are not authenticating, as I am getting the "fail: unable to authenticate" message. I can easily connect using the web server's terminal directly using the same information. Values are generic, for obvious reasons. If it means anything, the SSH server is a Mac running Mountain Lion (it runs OS X VMs), and the web server runs Ubuntu 12.04.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
if(!($con = ssh2_connect('192.168.0.1', 22))){
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, 'myusername', 'mysecretpassword')) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
    } else {
        echo "okay: logged in...\n";

        // execute a command
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "mysshcommand" ))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {

            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $data = "";
            while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                $data .= $buf;
            }
            fclose($stream);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure but it's possible the server you're connecting to is using keyboard-interactive auth and not password auth. Using a client like PuTTY they'd look the same when in fact they're not.

My recommendation would be to use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

It'll try password authentication first and, if that fails, it'll try keyboard-interactive. And if even that fails you can get the logs with phpseclib, too, to see what it's doing. I'll walk you through that should it be necessary.